# Program is working when using "Step into" in debugging mode, but not when running. (Sockets)

Tags: java, sockets

I have three classes: Server, Client and Cap. I'm trying to send Cap from Server to Client and back through sockets. Server implements runnable and in the run-method there is a infinite while-loop that look like this:

```
try {
out.writeObject(new Cap());
out.flush();

Cap cap = (Cap) in.readObject();

boolean bol = false;

if(cap.getValue()==2) {

 bol = true;
 }

out.writeBoolean(bol);
out.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something is wrong");
                break;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something is wrong");}

}
```

In the run-method but before the while-loop I did this:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
```

In the Client-class I also have a while loop like this:

```
try {

     Cap cap = (Cap) in.readObject();

     textBox.setText(cap.toString());

     while(!JButtonHasBeendPressed) {

      }

      out.writeObject(cap);
      out.flush();
      bol = in.readBoolean();

      if(bol) {

       //Do something
      }
      else {
       //Do something else
       }
       JButtonHasBeendPressed = false;

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       //Do something
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      //Do something
   }
 }
```

Before the while-loop I did this:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

When I'm debugging the Client-program it works just exactly as I want - the program gets inside "if(bol)". When I run the program, Server can send the object to Client, but after that something goes wrong. As you can see in the code I have a JButton in the Client-class, that is setting JButtonHasBeendPressed = true, but nothing happens when I'm pressing it. I get no error messages, literally nothing happens.

When I'm debugging both the server and the client, a IOException occurs at out.writeBoolean(bol); in the Server-class.

Hank

Comment: Is server connected to client??

Comment: Yes, the server in the example is actually a clientcommunicater that is created when a client connects to the actual server. It is connecte d through the accept()-method

Comment: The problem seems to be with the while-loop that is waiting for the button to be pressed.

Comment: basically outputstream object is writing on stream .Do you want to write on console of client?